# Fibonacci Modified:How to fix this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have this problem in front of me and I can't figure out how to solve it.
It's about the series `0,1,1,2,5,29,866...` (Every number besides the first two is the sum of the squares of the previous two numbers `(2^2+5^2=29)`).
In the first part I had to write an algorithm (Not a native speaker so I don't really know the terminology) that would receive a place in the series and return it's value (`6 returned 29`)
This is how I wrote it:

```
public static int mod(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 0;
    if (n==2)
        return 1;
    else
        return (int)(Math.pow(mod(n-1), 2))+(int)(Math.pow(mod(n-2), 2));
}
```

However, now I need that the algorithm will receive a number and return the total sum up to it in the series `(6- 29+5+2+1+1+0=38`)
I have no idea how to do this, I am trying but I am really unable to understand recursion so far, even if I wrote something right, how can I check it to be sure? And how generally to reach the right algorithm?

Using any extra parameters is forbidden.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the funcion call inside a loop, no? or does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Has to be recursive.

Comment: The example doesn't look right. `6-29+5+2+1+1+0` is not `38`, and I'm wondering, how did that `6-` end up there?

Comment: I meant that if n=6 it return 38.

Comment: "6-" is being used to indicate that the input is 6 and the corresponding calculation follows.

Comment: So you are saying that you have to calculate `sum(n) = mod(n) + sum(n-1)` with `mod(n) = mod(n-1)^2 + mod(n-2)^2`, but you have to do it with exactly one method with exactly one parameter? You can't create `mod` and `sum` as separate methods, or any other helper methods, and you can't add extra parameters as is often done for recursive methods. Did I understand that right? That constraints are that restrictive?

Comment: You can use extra parameters only if you create them in the method mod(), so correct.

Comment: Does your recursive algorithm need to be static?  Also, are you allowed to build and reference an ArrayList or array as a class property?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do both `sum` and `mod` and *recursion* in a single method with only 1 parameter. Non-recursive would be very easy, though.

Comment: @Andreas it is possible - just not very elegant!

Comment: Please edit the title of your question into something more descriptive.

Comment: Looks like another version of fibonacci. Look my solution.

Answer (score 4):

We want:

```
mod(1) = 0
mod(2) = 0+1
mod(3) = 0+1+1
mod(4) = 0+1+1+2
mod(5) = 0+1+1+2+5
mod(6) = 0+1+1+2+5+29
```

and we know that each term is defined as something like:

```
   2^2+5^2=29
```

So to work out mod(7) we need to add the next term in the sequence x to mod(6).

Now we can work out the term using mod:

```
 x = term(5)^2 + term(6)^2
 term(5) = mod(5) - mod(4)
 term(6) = mod(6) - mod(5)
 x = (mod(5)-mod(4))^2 + (mod(6)-mod(5))^2
```

So we can work out mod(7) by evaluating mod(4),mod(5),mod(6) and combining the results.

Of course, this is going to be incredibly inefficient unless you memoize the function!

Example Python code:

```
def f(n):
    if n<=0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        return 1
    a=f(n-1)
    b=f(n-2)
    c=f(n-3)
    return a+(a-b)**2+(b-c)**2

for n in range(10):
    print f(n)
```

prints:

```
0
1
2
4
9
38
904
751701
563697636866
317754178345850590849300
```

Comment: @TNguyen I've added an implementation

Comment: Very nice approach - much more elegant than the hack I used!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a way of doing this with the constraints in your comments but it's a total hack. You need one method to do two things: find the current value and add previous values. One option is to use negative numbers to flag one of those function:

```
int f(int n) {
    if (n > 0)
        return f(-n) + f(n-1);
    else if (n > -2)
        return 0;
    else if (n == -2)
        return 1;
    else
        return f(n+1)*f(n+1)+f(n+2)*f(n+2);
}
```

The first 8 numbers output (before overflow) are:

```
0
1
2
4
9
38
904
751701
```

I don't recommend this solution but it does meet your constraints of being a single recursive method with a single argument.

Comment: That is an impressive solution!

Comment: this is incorrect:
0 -> 0
1 -> 0*0 + 1*1 = 1
2 -> 1*1 + 1*1 = 2
3 -> 2*2 + 1*1 = 5
4 -> 5*5 + 2*2 = 29
5-> 29*29 + 5*5 = 866
...

Comment: @zlakad any further details?

Comment: @zlakad you haven't read the question properly. You are showing the terms but OP wants the sum of all terms.

Comment: @sprinter I apologize - I didn't read the question to the end.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? :)

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 6; // Your number here.
    System.out.println(result(N));
  }

  private static long result(final int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return element(n) + result(n - 1);
    }
  }

  private static long element(final int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
      return 0L;
    } else if (n == 2) {
      return 1L;
    } else {
      return sqr(element(n - 2)) + sqr(element(n - 1));
    }
  }

  private static long sqr(final long x) {
    return x * x;
  }
}
```

Here is the idea that separate function (`element`) is responsible for finding n-th element in the sequence, and `result` is responsible for summing them up. Most probably there is a more efficient solution though. However, there is only one parameter.

Comment: OP has said that adding extra method is not allowed. Stupid constraint in my opinion, but that's what OP said.

Comment: Well, had fun solving anyways :) Going with one method seems to be quite advanced approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal.

We know that:

***f(n) = 0;   n < 2***

***f(n) = 1;   2 >= n <= 3***

***f(n) = f(n-1)^2 + f(n-2)^2;   n>3***

So:

```
f(0)= 0
f(1)= 0
f(2)= f(1) + f(0) = 1
f(3)= f(2) + f(1) = 1
f(4)= f(3) + f(2) = 2
f(5)= f(4) + f(3) = 5
and so on
```

According with this behaivor we must implement a recursive function to return:

***Total = sum f(n); n= 0:k; where k>0***

I read you can use a *static method* but not use more than one parameter into the function. So, i used a *static* variable with the *static method*, just for control the execution of loop:

```
class Dummy 
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int n=10;

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total for n:" + i +" = " + Dummy.f(i));
        }
    }

    private static int counter = 0;
    public static long f(int n)
    {   
        counter++;

        if(counter == 1)
        {
            long total = 0;
            while(n>=0)
            {    
                total +=  f(n);
                n--;
            }
            counter--;
            return total;
        }

        long result = 0;
        long n1=0,n2=0;

        if(n >= 2 && n <=3)
            result++; //Increase 1
        else if(n>3)
        {
            n1 = f(n-1);
            n2 = f(n-2);

            result = n1*n1 + n2*n2;
        }

        counter--;
        return result;
    }
}
```

the output:

```
--------------------------
Total for n:1 = 0
--------------------------
Total for n:2 = 1
--------------------------
Total for n:3 = 2
--------------------------
Total for n:4 = 4
--------------------------
Total for n:5 = 9
--------------------------
Total for n:6 = 38
--------------------------
Total for n:7 = 904
--------------------------
Total for n:8 = 751701
--------------------------
Total for n:9 = 563697636866
--------------------------
Total for n:10 = 9011676203564263700
```

I hope it helps you.

**UPDATE:** Here is another version without a *static method* and has the same output:

```
class Dummy 
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Dummy app = new Dummy();
        int n=10;

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("Total for n:" + i +" = " + app.mod(i));
        }
    }

    private static int counter = 0;
    public long mod(int n)
    {   
        Dummy.counter++;

        if(counter == 1)
        {
            long total = 0;
            while(n>=0)
            {    
                total +=  mod(n);
                n--;
            }
            Dummy.counter--;
            return total;
        }

        long result = 0;
        long n1=0,n2=0;

        if(n >= 2 && n <=3)
            result++; //Increase 1
        else if(n>3)
        {
            n1 = mod(n-1);
            n2 = mod(n-2);

            result = n1*n1 + n2*n2;
        }

        Dummy.counter--;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Non-recursive|Memoized**
You should not use recursion since it will not be good in performance.
Use memoization instead.

```
def FibonacciModified(n):
    fib = [0]*n
    fib[0],fib[1]=0,1
    for idx in range(2,n):
        fib[idx] = fib[idx-1]**2 + fib[idx-2]**2
    return fib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fib = FibonacciModified(8)
    for x in fib:
        print x
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
5
29
866
750797
```

The above will calculate every number in the series once[not more than that].
While in recursion an element in the series will be calculated multiple times irrespective of the fact that the number was calculated before.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/